# How to retrieve the value of a multi nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Data={
    0:{
       'country_two': "3",
       'country_one': "5",
       'med_dict':{
          0: {
              'endDate': "732",
              'endTime': "89",
             }
       },
     },
    1: {
        'country_four': "2",
        'country_three': "90",
        'med_dict': {
          0: {
              'endDate': "245",
              'endTime': "222",
              }
        },

    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the maximum value for med_dict['endDate'] in this above dictionary. How to retrieve data in such dictionary for specific key like 'med_dict'?

Comment: Try this - `print(Data[0]['med_dict'][0]['endTime'])`   then do your *max* for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start with something like this:  (skip last step on purpose, it's for you to get it, which is super straightforward) ;-)

```
for k in Data:
    print(Data[k]['med_dict'][0]['endDate'])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.   Here is a great visual platform - https://pythontutor.com/   find it's helpful to see program execution and DS.

Answer (score 1):

```
maxVal = Data.get(0).get('med_dict').get(0).get('endDate')
```

I would simplify that dictionary. Way too overly complicated.

Comment: It seems that you assume the maxVal is *fixed* in ```0``` key always?

Comment: A dictionary like that is probably a JSON object imported from some external source. It may be problematic to simplify it, specially if you need to generate new objects back.

Comment: @DanielHao Lol yes I am indeed assuming that.